# Uploading maps made using ArcGIS for Desktop to Google Maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, arcgis-10.2

I've made a few maps using ArcGIS for Desktop. I wanted to know if it was possible to upload these maps onto Google Maps.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you just looking at overlaying shapefiles overtop of a basemap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map To KML (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004p000000) to convert a map document to the KML format readable in Google Earth or Google Maps.  If you have simple features, such as a transparent polygon layer with a certain color scheme use [Layer To KML (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000).  Once the KML is created, simply double-click it and it will automatically bring up Google Earth and zoom to your map data.

The process to get your data into Google Maps is a bit more involved.  Try the following workflow:

1) Convert map to KMZ using the above tools.  Note-a KMZ is a compressed KML

2) Use 7-zip to convert the KMZ to KML: Right-click KMZ > 7-zip >    Extract Here

3) Open Google Map in browser

4) Click on search area and select "My custom maps"

[image]

5) Create

[image]

6) Add KML

[image]

And the final map...Keep in mind that Google Maps gets finicky with large datasets.  Google Earth handles large datasets better and accepts KMZ files.

[image]

*Additional Resources:*

- [What is KML?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s20000000m000000)
- [A quick tour of KML in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s20000000p000000)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [google's API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

If you simply want to overlay your shapefiles on top of google maps you may have to [convert to KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387042/best-way-to-overlay-an-esri-shapefile-on-google-maps).

If you're looking at creating an interactive mapping website I would also check out [Open Street Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) as a base.